# Attempting to use 'sanity start' CLI results in 'command not found'

Tags: sanity

npm install -g @sanity/cli

sanity init

$ sanity start

bash: sanity: command not found

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If the installation was successful, it could be that the Sanity CLI wasn't added to your path. Which operating system are you on? If Mac or Linux, running `which sanity` in your terminal should show a path like `/usr/local/bin/sanity`. Running `echo $PATH` in your terminal, you would need to see `/usr/local/bin` somewhere in that path.